# Some Links and Tutorials to learn ffmpeg

Tags: android, android-ndk, ffmpeg

Can anyone provide me some good and easy link and tutorials to learn `ffmpeg` for android development.

Answer (score 2):

This both ones are the best in my opinion. Worked good for me:

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-android-applications-based-on-ffmpeg-by-an-example/

Comment: http://rowntreerob.wordpress.com/2012/06/17/ffmpeg-on-android-adding-vmware-and-ubuntu-to-best-practice/

Answer (score 0):

These links may help you with ffmpeg in android:

http://dmitrydzz-hobby.blogspot.in/2012/04/how-to-build-ffmpeg-and-use-it-in.html

http://vec.io/posts/how-to-build-ffmpeg-with-android-ndk